# Python Pandas: list of dicts in column, create list of specifc dict key as output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to parse a dataframe column called `'tags'` that contains a list of dicts and as an output create a list of the values of the key `var1`:

Dataframe column 'tags' example value:

```
[{'var1': 'blue','var2': 123,'var3': 888},{'var1': 'red','var2': 123,'var3': 888},{'var1': 'green','var2': 123,'var3': 888}]
```

desired output:

```
['blue', 'red', 'green']
```

code:

```
d = [{f'{k}{i}': v for i, y in enumerate(x, 1) for k, v in y.items() if k == 'var1'} for x in df['tags']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=df.index).sort_index(axis=1)
```

However this produces the following error:

```
Type Error: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I have tried converting both `i` and `v` to a string using `str(i)` and `str(v)`, however I am still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[item['var1'] for item in l]` if all dictionaries in the list has `var1` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error obviously means some missing values instead lists, for avoid it add `if-else` with empty lists in ouput if missing in `tags`:

```
df['new'] = [[] if isinstance(x, float) else [y.get('var1') for y in x] for x in df['tags']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.tag.apply(lambda x:x['var1']).tolist()
```